# Pagedown's Markdown.Editor() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, pagedown

I am trying to implement the Pagedown editor, following the example from this page: [Pagedown Demo](http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html). Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
<textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input"></textarea>
```

*(Note: The preview area missing is intentional)*

**JavaScript:**

```
var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
var editor = Markdown.Editor(converter);
editor.run();
```

However, `editor` is undefined in this instance. This is how the editor seems to work looking at the example code in the demo. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may be missing the wmd-panel...

```
<div class="wmd-panel">
    <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
    <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input">
</div>
```